# What can I do with delisted ADR (LTM)?

Tags: adr

As of today, LATAM Airline has been delisted from the NYSE. I was wondering what I could do with the situation. From what I know:

1) I could wait and see if it goes to OTC and trade there

2) Trade has been halted and stock is delisted, so I should just get rid of it from my portfolio and do the tax work.

What else can I do?